Storing and retrieving variable names and values in a table
I am trying to refer to an existing public variable and change it's value based upon a table which stores the variable name and value.
I have a table with three fields, an ID, a variable name, and a variable value.
In VBA I declared each variable and is the same as the [variable name] in the table. The purpose of the VBA code is to assign the variable the value based upon the table.
I loop through the records in the table and identify the declared variable using the IDs in the table.
For example in the table:
ID       VariableName      VariableValue
1        strStop                      x
2        strPause                     y
3        strGo                        z

Then I created a VBA recordset that loops through each record, and using a Select Case on the ID, populates the declared variable with the value found in the recordset.
In simple form:
Dim strStop as string
Dim strPause as string
Dim strGo as string

Do until rst.EOF
   Select Case rst!ID
      Case 1
         strStop = rst!VariableValue
      Case 2
         strPause = rst!VariableValue
      Case 3
         strGo = rst!VariableValue
   End Select
   rst.MoveNext
Loop

I would really like to remove the 'Select Case' and populate the already declared variables with the values contained in the table. Something along the lines of:
Dim strStop as string
Dim strPause as string
Dim strGo as string

Do until rst.EOF
   Name of declared variable (rst!VariableName) = rst!VariableValue
   rst.MoveNext
Loop


Sounds like you're describing a Dictionary.

That said, three different variables seems like overkill.  Your ID already contains the information about which operation it is (Stop, Pause or Go), and so your VariableValue really only needs to be stored in one place, if you also store the ID.

That VBA can't do. Also, reading a dozen or so variables as you currently do is very fast. Any other method - reading the records into an array, a collection, or similar - will be more convoluted.

Please don't take the example as actual data. In reality, each variable is essentially unique and utilised for different unrelated functions (and there are far more than three different variables)

There's no way in VBA to do what you describe - if there's a variable var there's no simple way to get that into a string "var".   The dictionary approach suggested by Robert is probably the closest, or keep your Select Case approach

What would be real data in VariableValue? Is this data subject to periodic changes? Frankly, I don't even understand what you are trying to accomplish. Is ID saved as a foreign key in another table? As @HansUp showed, DLookup could pull data as easily (easier?) as looping recordset.

@Robert Harvey
Many thanks for this idea. I've never used the dictionary functionality before and the link you kindly provided certainly explains the concept clearly and simply. I'll look deeper into this in the office this week. Once again, many thanks
